# Artefact-less Email Client (Windows)?

Tags: windows, email, email-client, forensics

I've found the Windows 10 Mail App to be user-friendly, but I don't like how it saves all emails and attachments to disk as this can be bad for security and privacy.

I'm looking for an email-client which supports multiple providors (e.g. Outlook, Gmail) but which doesn't save any email information to disk. The closest way I can think of is an electron style client with disk cache disabled, but I'm unaware of any such email clients.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email client which does not download copies of emails to my local machine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46532/email-client-which-does-not-download-copies-of-emails-to-my-local-machine)

Comment: Thanks, but according to a post [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1036620), it seems that Thunderbird still caches? The post is from six years ago though so not sure if things have changed since then.

Comment: At some point, it's very likely that at least some part of the data will hit the disk and memory, petty much every email client will use some temp folders at least. Your next best bet will be some webmail, not a real email client. Browser cache will be your only concern then.